# Split string on whitespace in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split, whitespace

I'm looking for the Python equivalent of

```
String str = "many   fancy word \nhello    \thi";
String whiteSpaceRegex = "\\s";
String[] words = str.split(whiteSpaceRegex);

["many", "fancy", "word", "hello", "hi"]
```

Answer (score 1191, accepted):

The [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method without an argument splits on whitespace:

```
>>> "many   fancy word \nhello    \thi".split()
['many', 'fancy', 'word', 'hello', 'hi']
```

Comment: Also good to know is that if you want the first word only (which means passing `1` as second argument), you can use `None` as the first argument: `s.split(None, 1)`

Comment: If you only want the first word, use *str.partition*.

Comment: @yak : Can you please edit your comment. The way it sounds right now is that s.split(None, 1) would return 1st word only. It rather gives a list of size 2. First item being the first word, second - rest of the string. `s.split(None, 1)[0]` would return the first word only

Comment: Also the default split trims whitespace from either side so you don't have to call str.strip() e.g.        `" asdf  asdf  \t\n ".split()` returns `['asdf', 'asdf']`

Comment: does `str.split()` do something like `re.split('\s+', string)` behind the scenes?

Comment: @galois No, it uses a custom implementation (which is faster).  Also note that it handles leading and trailing whitespace differently.

Comment: Sven, in my case line, could contain words like `'Kishor Pawar' 'Sven Marnach'`. What would you suggest?

Comment: @KishorPawar It's rather unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to split on whitespace, but disregard whitespace inside single-quoted substrings? If so, you can look into [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split), which may be what you are looking for. Otherwise I suggest asking a new question – you will get a much quicker and more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you @SvenMarnach. You guessed the case correctly. I will take a look at shelx.split()

Answer (score 91):

```
import re
s = "many   fancy word \nhello    \thi"
re.split('\s+', s)
```

Comment: this gives me a whitespace token at the end of the line. No idea why, the original line doesn't even have that. Maybe this ignores newline?

Comment: @Gulzar do a `strip()` at the end

Comment: Note that this is usually slower than str.split if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 30):

Using `split()` will be the most *Pythonic* way of splitting on a string.

It's also useful to remember that if you use `split()` on a string that does not have a whitespace then that string will be returned to you in a list.

Example:

```
>>> "ark".split()
['ark']
```

Answer (score 22):

Another method through `re` module. It does the reverse operation of matching all the words instead of spitting the whole sentence by space.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "many   fancy word \nhello    \thi"
>>> re.findall(r'\S+', s)
['many', 'fancy', 'word', 'hello', 'hi']
```

Above regex would match one or more non-space characters.