# Regular expression Python for Splitting at all whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string on whitespace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

I have a string like so:

```
['.text      0x1000       0xb51b       0xb600       6.259216    ']
```

and I would like to split it into this:

```
[.text, 0x1000, 0xb51b... etc]
```

So far I've tried:
    re.split("( )*", b)
and
    re.split("[ \t*]", b)

but to no avail. I get things like:

```
.['.text', ' ', '0x1000', ' ', '0xb51b', ' ', '0xb600', ' ', '6.259216', ' ', '']
```

or some others with even more whitespaces. I know I could just remove the whitespaces from the string but I would much rather just straight up use a RE to split them in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use the regular [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

```
'.text      0x1000       0xb51b       0xb600       6.259216    '.split()
```

To quote the documentation:

> if sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

---

As an aside, I've found that using `mystring.split(None)` (as opposed to `mystring.split()`) is sometimes quite a useful thing to keep in mind as it allows you to not "hardcode" the splitting algorithm.

Comment: Because the amount of spaces vary

Comment: @Shelby.S -- That doesn't matter.  -- Give it a try :-)

Comment: .split() would take all whitespaces into account. This would work

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re
re.split("\s*", yourInputString.strip()) # result as List
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to firstly clear the multiple whitespaces, and replace them with single white spaces. After that you you do a `split(" ")` with one whitespace:

```
re.sub(r"  +"," ", text).split(" ")
```

Comment: Why would you ever use this if you can do it all in 1 go with `str.split`?  I suppose you if you wanted to make sure that you didn't split on `"\t"` or something ...

Comment: Of course, in this case, it's easier to just use `re.split(' +',string_to_split)`

Comment: I agree with you. For the specific purpose as in this question, the `str.split` is most appropriate. But if you have some other multicharacter occurences, then my solution is maybe more general.

Comment: You're right... Totally forgot about `re.split` .