# Python regex splitting on multiple whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, string

I am expecting a user input string which I need to split into separate words.
The user may input text delimited by commas or spaces.

So for instance the text may be:

`hello world this is John`.
or

`hello    world this     is      John` or even

`hello world,    this, is       John`

How can I efficiently parse that text into the following list?

`['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'John']`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried `r'/\s+/g'` yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string on whitespace in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: Problem is I don't know if the user will use commas or whitespaces. Therefore I need a solution to cover it all.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the commas. The title is kind of misleading. Have you looked into `re.split`? Where is your current attempt failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to split based on spaces and other special characters, the best RegEx would be `\W+`. Quoting from [Python re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

> #### \W
>
> When the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are not specified, matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the set `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. With `LOCALE`, it will match any character not in the set [0-9_], and not defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match anything other than `[0-9_]` plus characters classified as not alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

For Example,

```
data = "hello world,    this, is       John"
import re
print re.split("\W+", data)
# ['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'John']
```

Or, if you have the list of special characters by which the string has to be split, you can do

```
print re.split("[\s,]+", data)
```

This splits based on any whitespace character (`\s`) and comma (`,`).

Comment: Thank you. Clean and effective solution. However not that only `print re.split("[\s,]+", data)` worked. Maybe it's the fact that I'm under Windows.

Comment: Yes. \W+ method returned an empty list for me. However the re.split method worked perfectly good.

Comment: @Konos5 I actually tested it before posting here. So, if you could help me reproduce the problem with some sample data, it would be good :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the regular expression: `r'[\s,]+'` to split on ***1 or more*** white-space characters (`\s`) or commas (`,`).

```
import re

s = 'hello world,    this, is       John'
print re.split(r'[\s,]+', s)
```

> `['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'John']`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = "hello      world this     is            John"
>>> s.split()
['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'John']
>>> s = "hello world, this, is John"
>>> s.split()
['hello', 'world,', 'this,', 'is', 'John']
```

The first one is correctly parsed by split with no arguments ;)

Then you can :

```
>>> s = "hello world, this, is John"
>>> def notcoma(ss) :
...     if ss[-1] == ',' :
...             return ss[:-1]
...     else :
...             return ss
... 
>>> map(notcoma, s.split())
['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'John']
```

Comment: He has to split based on special characters as well