# splitting a list of sentences into separate words in a list

Tags: python

I have a list which consists of lines as

```
lines =  ['The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.',
     'New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns',
     'DFAs with correction equivalence queries.',
     'general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.']
```

I need to store it in the list as 'Separate words'

```
lines =  ['The','query', 'complexity' ,'of' ,'estimating', 'weighted','averages.'
     ,'New' ......]
```

How to obtain it as a list of separate words?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lines =  [
...     'The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.',
...     'New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns',
... ]
>>> [word for line in lines for word in line.split()]
['The', 'query', 'complexity', 'of', 'estimating', 'weighted','averages.', 'New', 'bounds', 'for', 'the', 'query', 'complexity', 'of', 'an', 'algorithm', 'that', 'learns']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join all lines and then use `split()`:

```
" ".join(lines).split()
```

or you can split each line and chain:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*map(str.split, lines)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

lines =  ['The query complexity of estimating weighted averages.',
 'New bounds for the query complexity of an algorithm that learns',
 'DFAs with correction equivalence queries.',
 'general procedure to check conjunctive query containment.']

joint_words = ' '.join(lines)

separated_words = word_tokenize(joint_words)

print(separated_words)
```

Output will be :

```
['The', 'query', 'complexity', 'of', 'estimating', 'weighted', 'averages', '.', 'New', 'bounds', 'for', 'the', 'query', 'complexity', 'of', 'an', 'algorithm', 'that', 'learns', 'DFAs', 'with', 'correction', 'equivalence', 'queries', '.', 'general', 'procedure', 'to', 'check', 'conjunctive', 'query', 'containment', '.']
```

In addition, if you want to merge the dots with previous string (which appear as independent strings in the list), run the following code:

```
for i, j in enumerate(separated_words):
    if '.' in j:
        separated_words[i-1] = separated_words[i-1] + separated_words[i]
        del separated_words[i]    # For deleting duplicate entry

print(separated_words)
```

Output will be:

```
['The', 'query', 'complexity', 'of', 'estimating', 'weighted', 'averages.', 'New', 'bounds', 'for', 'the', 'query', 'complexity', 'of', 'an', 'algorithm', 'that', 'learns', 'DFAs', 'with', 'correction', 'equivalence', 'queries.', 'general', 'procedure', 'to', 'check', 'conjunctive', 'query', 'containment.']
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python) where a string is split based on whitespace:

```
lines[0].split()
```

The above would split your lines list (which seems to contain 1 item) using the whitespace in that string.