# Parse values in text file

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've got a .txt [file](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipwOCxo4nRAhUSM8AKHQWqC4gQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopenweathermap.org%2Fhelp%2Fcity_list.txt&usg=AFQjCNH0lMyV3LTLGYc-1873FPz4zS4e4g&sig2=qa9PSEcgt2C3GSCmZDbXaw) that looks like this:

```
id        nm        lat        lon        countryCode
5555555  London    55.876456   99.546231   UK
```

I need to parse each field and add them to a SQLite database. So far I've managed to transfer into my db the id, name and countryCode columns, but I'm struggling to find a solution to parse the lat and lon of each record individually.

I tried with regex, but no luck. I also thought about making a parser to check if the last non-whitespace char is a letter, to determine that the string is lat and not lon, but have no idea how to implement it correctly. Can I solve it using regex or should I use a custom parser? if so, how?

Comment: I think I might do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python

Comment: Why not just split the data rows by space since they're all in the same order column-wise? All you really need to do is go line by line and do id, nm, lat, lon, cc = line.split()

Comment: You can do that in 1 line using pandas. `df = pandas.read_csv('file_path', sep='\t')` And then insert the entire dataframe into your SQLite db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('path/new.db')
con.text_factory = str

df = pd.read_csv('file_path', sep='\t')
df.to_sql('table_01', con)
```

If there are bad lines and you can afford to skip them then use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_path', sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
```

[Read more.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the text file, it looks like it's always the same format for each line. As such, why not just split like this:

```
for line in lines:
    id, nm, lat, lon, code = line.split()
    # Insert into SQLite db
```

With `split()` you don't have to worry about how much whitespace there is between each token of the string.

Comment: `id, nm, lat, lon, code = s` is better for clarity and more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

using [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
txt = '5555555  London    55.876456   99.546231   UK'
(id, nm, lat, lon, countryCode) = txt.split()
```