# python - strings/lists not slicing well, cannot get longest word

Tags: python

I'm kind of a beginner, and no searches could answer my problem.
I'm trying to find the longest word in a string if a word is defined as a set of English characters next to each other.
Dictionaries not allowed, iI'm stuck on the splitting part with  replacing non-alpha chars with spaces.

Comment: Please provide some example code of the problem, and your attempted solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: `max(re.split("[^a-z]+",target_text,re.I),key=len)` I guess...

Comment: The `str.translate` method is useful for replacing a bunch of chars in a string. Or you could just use a loop and `str.isalpha`.

Comment: @PM2Ring OP only thinks they need to replace with whitespace... as far as i can tell from problem statement you dont need to do that...

Comment: @JoranBeasley They need actual word lengths, so simply splitting on whitespace isn't enough. They need to deal with the punctuation chars too. Sure, they could do it your way, with a regex, but it's easy enough using `str` methods.

Comment: Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Providing some code sample could go a long way.