# prevent word split based on - in sentences

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

This:

```
import re

title = 'Decreased glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase activity along with oxidative stress affects visual contrast sensitivity in alcoholics.'

words = list(filter(None, re.split('\W+', title)))
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

results in:

```
Decreased
glucose
6
phosphate
dehydrogenase
activity
along
with
oxidative
stress
affects
visual
contrast
sensitivity
in
alcoholics
```

Ideally, I would like to prevent the splitting of words like:

```
glucose-6-phosphate
```

Is there a better way to obtain separate words of a sentence like this in Python? Should I adopt the regular expression or is there something OOTB? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: I do not think that this is answered in the link provided as str.split() does not work see comment to answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern \W splits at this grouping: [^a-zA-Z0-9_] so to stop it splitting on hyphens simply add one to this pattern and use it in your regex:

```
words = list(filter(None, re.split('[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', title)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\W+` means a sequence of characters (letters). Since `-` is not among those characters, the sentence is split there. Since you only seem to split at spaces, you don't need a regular expression, you can just `title.split()`.