# Breaking line into a list, detecting spaces in Python

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm trying to read data from a text file into Python. The file consists of lines like this:

```
SAMPLE_0001 2000    57  1   103 51  0   NA
```

For ease of data management, I'd like to save that line as a list:

```
[SAMPLE_0001,2000,57,1,103,51,0,NA]
```

I wrote the following function to do that:

```
def line_breaker(line):
    words=[]
    if line[0]==' ':
        in_word=False
    else:
        in_word=True
    word=[]    
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if in_word==True and line[i]!=' ':
            word.append(line[i])
        elif in_word==True and line[i]==' ':
            in_word=False
            words.append(word)
            word=[]
        elif in_word==False and line[i]!=' ':
            in_word=True
            word.append(line[i])
        if i==len(line)-1 and line[i]!=' ':
            word.append(line[i])
            words.append(word)
    return words
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as intended. When I apply it to the example above, I get the whole line as one long string. On closer inspection, this was because the condition `line[i]==' '` failed to trigger on the blank spaces. I guess I should replace `' '` with something else.

When I ask Python to print the 11th position in the example, it displays nothing. That's totally unhelpful. I then asked it to print the type of the 11th position in the example; I got `<class 'str'>`.

So what should I use to detect spaces?

Comment: Why not just use `"SAMPLE_0001 2000 57 1 103 51 0 NA".split()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: Ask Python to print the character code (`ord`) instead - it might not be a space. "Whitespace" covers a lot of codes, so many that it needs a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isspace#str.isspace) to check.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. Unfortunately, a simple use of .split(' ') isn't working. Looks like Python is failing to recognize the whitespaces as whitespaces at all. Going to look into the links.

Comment: @usr2564301 How do I ask Python to print the character code (ord)?

Comment: It's just a regular function. See [`ord` in the Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn a string seperated by whitespaces into an array the best way (as some above has mentioned is the built in `split(' ')` function). But if you dont want to use that you could use `isspace()` and do it manually in a custom function like this:

```
def line_breaker():
    my_array = []
    string = list(input("Write Your string:\n"))
    last_whitespace = int()

    for index, element in enumerate(string):
        if(element.isspace()):
            my_array.append("".join(string[last_whitespace:index]))
            last_whitespace = index + 1

    print(my_array)
```

Comment: Couldn't get .split() to work; but replacing ```==' '``` with .```isspace()==True``` worked! Thanks

Comment: Great to hear it working! But you don't need `isspace()==True` since `isspace()` returns a boolean so you are just asking if `True == True` or `False == True` when you can just use `True`.

TLDR; Use `.isspace()` instead of `.isspace() == true` since `isspace()` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`, as usual – you'll just have to remember to not *explicitly* split on *spaces* alone, as in:

```
myNaiveSplit = text.split(' ')
```

because that will **absolutely fail** if, as in your case, there may be some other whitespace character between the words.

Instead, don't provide any argument at all. After all, the [official documentation on `split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) tells us so:

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: **runs of consecutive whitespace** are regarded as a single separator ...
>   (my emphasis)

and the 'whitespace' mentioned is everything which is considered "whitespace" by the function [`isspace`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) (which is fully Unicode-compliant).

So all you need is

```
mySmartSplit = text.split()
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `split`?

```py
line = "SAMPLE_0001 2000 57 1 103 51 0 NA"
print(line.split(' '))
['SAMPLE_0001', '2000', '57', '1', '103', '51', '0', 'NA']
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
line = "SAMPLE_0001 2000 57 1 103 51 0 NA"
line = line.split(" ")
```

You'll get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Do  it like this

```
delimiter = ' '
with open(file) as f: 
 for line in f.readlines():
  split_line = line.split(delimiter)
     # do your thing with the list of words
```

Answer (score -1):

split() work perfectly.

```
strr= "SAMPLE_0001 2000 57 1 103 51 0 NA"
print(strr.split(' '))
```

split() changes sentences into python list according to your need. For example, strr.split(',') will split by comma.