# How print a list into separate lists python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
grades= ['doe john     100  90  80  90', 'miller sally  70  90  60 100  80', 'smith jakob   45  55  50  58', 'white jack    85  95  65  80  75']
```

I want to be able to break that list so the output would be:

```
['doe john     100  90  80  90']
['miller sally  70  90  60 100  80']
['smith jakob   45  55  50  58']
['white jack    85  95  65  80  75']
```

Additionally, I would like to split the elements in the list so it looks like:

```
['doe', 'john',     '100',  '90',  '80',  '90']
['miller', 'sally',  '70',  '90',  '60', '100',  '80']
['smith', 'jakob',   '45',  '55',  '50',  '58']
['white', 'jack',    '85',  '95',  '65',  '80',  '75']
```

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this or if this is even possible as I'm just starting to learn python. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried so far and where you’re getting stuck.  Hint, yes.  It’s very possible and quite simple.  Give it a try.

Comment: I understand you want to make a list of lists, you can move from step1 to step3 in one line of code. Try to take a look to the ```split``` function

Answer (score 2):

```py
for l in grades:
    l = l.split()
```

OR

```py
final = [l.split() for l in grades]
```

See [Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quickly with `.split()` in a list comprehension.

```py
grades = ['doe john     100  90  80  90', 'miller sally  70  90  60 100  80', 'smith jakob   45  55  50  58', 'white jack    85  95  65  80  75']

grades = [grade.split() for grade in grades]
print (grades)
```