# How do I format a string to create an iterable list?

Tags: python, string, list, format

I have a string containing multiple institutions of the following form:

'Harvard University

Yale University

...

'

Where the collection of institutions are contained in a singular string and each institution is separated by a space of size larger than one. How do I join/format the string so that it can appear in a list like [Harvard University, Yale University,..]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string on whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: BTW "join" and "format" usually mean the *opposite* of what you want to do.

Comment: oh apologies, but yes that link was helpful thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
list_of_institutions = institutions.split("\n")
```