# How to check a part of an input | Python

Tags: python, list, input, indexing

**I want to check a specific part of an input but I don't know "where" it is**

I tried with this:
a = input('Enter command')

```
if a[0:5] == '(Command name)':

    if a[7:?] == '(Subject)':

        if a[?:len(a)] == '(Choice)':

            To be continued
```

So, the input is divided into three parts; The command, the subject, and which type of the command it will run.
But which index should the ? be? I don't know the length of the word. Is it impossible?

**No**, I know that I can make it, just not how.

Comment: If you need more complicated parsing, try checking out `argparse`.

Comment: Or did you want to find out [how to split strings on whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113782/split-string-on-whitespace-in-python)?

Comment: you don't need `len(a)` there - just leave it blank `a[?:]`

Answer (score 0):

If they are always one word, maybe something like this will work:

```
terms = a.strip().split(" ")
command_name = terms[0]
subject = terms[1]
choice = terms[2]
```

if there is a possibility of double spaces, it needs to be more clever

---

the above is the same as

```
command_name, subject, choice = a.strip().split(" ")
```

Comment: Wow, you really gets your answer fast. Thanks

Comment: Btw do you mean `command_name = terms[0]`?

Comment: oh yeah - fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your input should go something like this:

```
command subject choice
```

So there are basically three parts(might be more). I suggest you break the input in list as:

```
a = [str(x) for x in input().split()]
```

To get the length of each entities:

```
len(entity)
```

And for index you can use index():

```
list.index(entity)
```